# Finding or changing items on same table row based on a column value or values

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I struggled with this for a long, long time so hopefully this will help someone.

The problem was this:

- I needed to find a row by matching one or more specific cell values
- Then change the value of one or more cells in that same row.
- Compounding the problem was that the value within these cells may be nested by multiple and varying number of DIV's (and potentially other HTML tags).

Below is a bit of contrived HTML but hopefully illustrate the point:

```
<table>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Middle Name</th>
    <th>Family Name</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><div><div><span>John</span></div></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span>Smith</span></td>
            <td><span>Nice guy.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><div><div><div><div><span>John</span></div></div></div></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span>Doe</span></td>
            <td><span>Jolly decent cricketer.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><div><div><div><div><span>Jane</span></div></div></div></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span>Doe</span></td>
            <td><span>Great swimmmer.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><span>Jack</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span>Sprat</span></td>
            <td><span>Spiffing golfer.</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The question is is there a more or less generic way of getting to the checkbox of John Doe, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Try below:-

```
//tbody/tr/td[text()='John']/following-sibling::td[text()='Doe']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Here, we try to find 'td' tag having text **John** and its following sibling i.e. 'td' tag such that it has text **Doe**.  Once, this is done, then we try to find preceding siblings which is first in order for checkbox.
This is more robost, means it does not take into account order of first name and last name in markup.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion. It works, but not in the situation I mentioned, i.e. with varying number of DIVs (or other HTML tags) between TD and SPAN. But still, it threw up very interesting results when I experimented with your solution. I'll explain

Comment: The table is large. The span text is here: /table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/span[2], and the checkbox is here: /table/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]/div/input. This won't find and TD siblings: //table/tbody/tr/td[2]//span[position()=2 and text()='XYZ']/following-sibling::td. I have to do this: //table/tbody/tr/td[2]//span[position()=2 and text()='XYZ']/../../../../../../../following-sibling::td. But because I don't know how many nested DIVs in advance I can't use following-sibling in this way.

Comment: Continuing from above. This 'works': //table/tbody/tr/td[position()=2 and //span[position()=2 and text()='XYZ']]/following-sibling::td, but gives completely the wrong answer. 'XYZ' is unique in the table but in FireFox, it found 150 matches! Not only that but it took over 5 mins to execute! Whereas my original solution, though not optimum, was fairly instantaneous. Still, I very much appreciate your comment. It adds more strings to my bow and I'm sure it'll be helpful in the appropriate situation.

Answer (score 1):

First, note the varying levels of DIVs under the First Name column. This makes finding the 'preceding-sibling' or 'following-sibling' TD virtually impossible.

The trick is to use **'ancestor'** to navigate up to the row, TR, and then index the appropriate cell from that vantage point, and you can do this for multiple matches.

E.g. There are two Johns in the above example, so to get the right checkbox you need to match both First Name and Family Name (John Doe). Here's the xpath to do that:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[2]//span[text()='John']/ancestor::tr/td[4]/span[text()='Doe']/ancestor::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Of course, the above now opens up the possibility of anchoring on this row and performing find or actions on neighbouring rows and their cells.

Hope this helps someone as much as it's helped me!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go up and down the tree so often.

Locate the `tr` element checking for the `span` elements texts anywhere inside the `td` children:

```
//tr[td[2]//span = 'John' and td[4]//span = 'Doe']/input[@type = 'checkbox']
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. As far as I can see, this is better than my solution. Many thanks.